# Custom keyboard not showing correct cursor position if user change language to Arabic from application setting

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, custom-keyboard

This question might be asked by someone but i do not found any relevant answer for it.

I am creating a keyboard extension, it has multi language support but problem is when user select Arabic language from application setting and then typing anything to input view but cursor position is not changing.
[Below image has extension plist settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL7M1.png)

I have added below UITextInputDelegate

- (void)textWillChange:(id)textInput
- (void)textDidChange:(id)textInput

But above delegate methods are calling only once the keyboard launch and its "**textInput**" is nil always, if i am typing anything it is not getting called anymore.

Any help can highly be appreciated.